# Javascript - Finding the N closest points to a given point (2D)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I need an algorithm to sort through a list of ~2,500 [longitude, latitude] arrays to find the N closest points to a given [longitude, latitude]. The particular use case is finding the closest taxis for ride hailing

I have searched through online resources and most of them point toward only the minimum value. I have wrote some code where I looped through the list via a forEach and calculated the Euclidean distance to the point of interest, placed the distances into an array, sorted it, then extracted the 3 smallest distances, but then I had to find the indexes of the smallest distances, which leads to a high runtime. I also considered KNN but felt it was overcomplicating the problem

Is there a more efficient way to loop through and extract the 3 closest points? For example, some built-in method?

Edit: Here's an example:

Point of interest: `[103, 1.3]`

Data:

```js
[
    [103.6632, 1.32287], [103.66506, 1.30803], [103.67088, 1.32891],
    [103.67636, 1.3354], [103.67669, 1.32779], [103.67927, 1.31477],
    [103.67927, 1.32757], [103.67958, 1.31458], [103.68508, 1.32469],
    [103.6927, 1.3386], [103.69367, 1.34], [103.69377, 1.37058],
    [103.69431, 1.37161], [103.69519, 1.35543], [103.69538, 1.34725],
    [103.6961, 1.33667], [103.696918716667, 1.35110788333333],
    [103.69731, 1.35], [103.698615333333, 1.33590666666667],
    [103.69975, 1.35], [103.70129, 1.34], [103.70247, 1.34],
    [103.70366, 1.34], [103.70394, 1.33948], [103.70403, 1.34081],
    [103.704697166667, 1.33546383333333], [103.70504, 1.34],
    [103.706281333333, 1.344646], [103.70689, 1.34464]
]
```

Comment: You might want to brush up on the [Haversine formula](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/58653)

Comment: Thanks for this. I did notice the Haversine formula appear in one of the existing StackOverflow posts but it's a distance measure rather than an algorithm. Nonetheless I'll switch over to Haversine for more accurate distance calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] placed the distances into an array, sorted it, then extracted the 3 smallest distances, but then I had to find the indexes of the smallest distances

You can simply populate that array with both indices and distances at the same time.

```js
let array = [[1, 230], [2, 222], [3, 810], [4, 125], [5, 441]];
array.sort((a, b) => a[1]-b[1]);
array.forEach(([index, distance]) => console.log(index, ':', distance));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please elaborate on how the `sort()` sorts the array by the closest distance to a given coordinate, such as [2.5, 500]?

Comment: @jingwen the example shows how the array can be prepared for sorting. Instead of populating it like `array.push(distance)`, you can do `array.push([index, distance])`. So you can easily access the original points for which you have calculated these distances.

Comment: I see... would you happen to know how to apply the `sort()` function to a 3D array based on the first index? It would be sorting by distance in `[distance, latitude, longitude]`

Comment: @jingwen `array.sort((a, b) => a[0]-b[0])` will sort it in ascending order. BTW, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is your best friend when it comes to learn anything about vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
const data=[
         [103.6632, 1.32287], [103.66506, 1.30803], [103.67088, 1.32891],[103.67636, 1.3354], [103.67669, 1.32779], [103.67927, 1.31477],[103.67927, 1.32757], [103.67958, 1.31458], [103.68508, 1.32469],[103.6927, 1.3386], [103.69367, 1.34], [103.69377, 1.37058],[103.69431, 1.37161], [103.69519, 1.35543], [103.69538, 1.34725],[103.6961, 1.33667], [103.696918716667, 1.35110788333333],[103.69731, 1.35], [103.698615333333, 1.33590666666667],[103.69975, 1.35], [103.70129, 1.34], [103.70247, 1.34],[103.70366, 1.34], [103.70394, 1.33948], [103.70403, 1.34081],[103.704697166667, 1.33546383333333], [103.70504, 1.34],[103.706281333333, 1.344646], [103.70689, 1.34464]
   ]
```

write distance function (there are different implementations):

```
function euclidian(pair1, pair2) {
  return Math.hypot(pair1[0] - pair2[0], pair1[1] - pair2[1]);
}
```

you have those constants

```
const k=7
const point=[103, 1.3]
```

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) utilities library:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
   // .chain wraps the data to enable chaining
 _.chain(data)
  .map((row,index)=>[euclidian(row,point),index])
  .sortBy(row=>row[0])
  .slice(0,7)
```

result is

```
[[0.6635942110205637,0],[0.6651084757391051,1],
[0.6715026154081575,2],[0.6772603932018993,4],
[0.6772857665712483,3],[0.6794305599544396,5],
[0.6797363847845737,7]]
```